# Agriculture commodity price predictions using machine learning

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, prediction

I want to create a web application which uses machine learning to predict the price of agriculture commodities before 2-3 months.

Is it really feasible or not?

If yes, then please provide some rough idea about which tools and technologies I can use to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, study **math**, more precisely, statistics and differential algebra.

Then, use any open (or not) source **neural networking libraries** you could find. Even MATLAB would help, as it has a good set of examples (I think it has some of alike prediction models, at least I remember creating a model for predicting election results in Poland)

Decide on your training and input data. Research how **news** and global situation influences commodity prices. Research how existing **bots** predict prices for next 1-2 minutes. Also consider using history of predictions from certain individuals, I think **Reuters** has some API for this. Saying this I imply you'll have to integrate natural language processors, too.

Train your model, test it, improve it for quite a long time.

Finally, deploy a boring front-end and monetize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to implement ML, you can also use kalman filters.

Comment: I have started working on it using Bayesian ridge regression in scikit learn. And thanks for suggestion.:)